# How to get the working directory of the cmake process?

Tags: cmake

How to get the working directory from which `cmake` was called?

I know that I can run `execute_process()` at the beginning of my CMake code but maybe there is some better way like a built-in variable to the working directory of the CMake process.

What I want to achieve is to convert a relative path given in a CMake variable (given with `-D...`) to an absolute path in CMake.

Comment: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR.html

Comment: No `CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR` points to a file in the source directory but I am calling `cmake` from somewhere else.

Comment: The working directory is relevant as I want the user to be able to give a path to some dependency outside of the the source tree and that path should always work, no matter if the user gives the path relative (to the directory `cmake` is invoked, e.g. to benefit by path completion in bash) or absolute. Also, I do not make assumption on how `cmake` is called (from the source dir / the build dir / somewhere else).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What I want to achieve is to convert a relative path given in a CMake variable (given with -D...) to an absolute path in CMake.

Then simply create a cache variable of type `PATH` (for directories) or `FILEPATH` in your CMakeLists.txt. CMake will convert untyped command line arguments to absolute paths automatically.

```
$ cat CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.22)
project(test NONE)

set(input_file "" CACHE FILEPATH "some input file")
message(STATUS "${input_file}")

$ cmake -S . -B build -Dinput_file=foo.txt
-- /path/to/foo.txt
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /path/to/build
```

See the documentation:

> It is possible for the cache entry to exist prior to the call but have no type set if it was created on the cmake(1) command line by a user through the `-D<var>=<value>` option without specifying a type. In this case the set command will add the type. Furthermore, if the `<type>` is `PATH` or `FILEPATH` and the `<value>` provided on the command line is a relative path, then the set command will treat the path as relative to the current working directory and convert it to an absolute path.

Here: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/set.html?highlight=current%20working%20directory

---

Relatedly, when running in *script mode* (rather than *project* mode), several of the usual variables are set to the current working directory:

> When run in `-P` script mode, CMake sets the variables `CMAKE_BINARY_DIR`, `CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR`, `CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR` and `CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR` to the current working directory.

https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR.html

Comment: Wow, awesome solution!